# css sub menu hover issue

Tags: html, css, menu, nav

I have a submenu and when I hover over the parent list it drops down like it is supposed to and everything is working with the hover color, but when i go back up to the parent list it doesnt show the hover color until I am at the very top/practically off the list..is this a padding issue?

```
/* MENU */


 #gen_navigation {

float:right;
margin:0;
padding:0;


 }

#gen_navigation li a, #gen_navigation li {
float:left;
}

 #gen_navigation li {

list-style:none;
position:relative;

}

 #gen_navigation li a {
padding: 35px 20px 23px 20px;
text-decoration:none;
color:white;
border-right: 1px solid #3c3c3c;
border-left: 1px solid #333;
border-bottom: 1px solid #232323;
border-radius:3px;
}

 /* Sub-Menu */
 #gen_navigation li ul {
display:none;
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:100%;
margin:0;
padding:0;
background: #292929;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, black, #3c3c3c 1px, #292929 25px);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left 25, from(black), color-stop(4%,   #3c3c3c), to(#292929)); 

}

  #gen_navigation li:hover ul {
display:block;

}
#gen_navigation li ul li, #gen_navigation li ul li a {
float:none;
}


#gen_navigation li ul li a {
 width: 180px;
 display: block;
}
```

and the html

```
 <ul id="gen_navigation">
            <li class="selected"><a href="#"><span>Home</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>About</span></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Gate 5 Energy Partners</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Leadership</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Key Consultants & Strategic Partners</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>Technology</span></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">About SERT</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About the inventor</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>Applications</span></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Agri-Business</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">WasteWater Industry</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>Benefits</span></a>
                <ul> 
                    <li><a href="#">Environmental Benefits</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Economic Benefits</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>Inquiries</span></a></li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: Here is this http://jsfiddle.net/YjLxy/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I was trying to get your code working, and I got it, but now I see that joholo sorted it out. Nevertheless, I think I have your fix: by using jQuery's `parents()`, I re-add the 'selected' class to your top `<li>`.

[Check this working example](http://jsfiddle.net/fabio_silva/YjLxy/13/)

By the way: I think your `.animate` does not work, so I guess you were trying to use jQuery-UI's `effect`. Check it out too.

Regards!

Comment: yeah that was giving me problems..what would I add to that so that when I hover off the first submenu item the hover goes away

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand you...Could you rephrase it?

Comment: sorry..when you hover over the sub menu and then you go back up to the parent list, is there a way that when you are hovering over the parent list item that the top child of that UL would remove the hover class..I hope that wasnt even more confusing, still learning the lingo

Comment: Oh, I get it now. Yes, you just have to use `mouseleave`. Check http://jsfiddle.net/fabio_silva/YjLxy/14/

Comment: ah i was so close! perfect thats just what I needed, you the man

Comment: Another thing: I've noticed that the bounce effect makes the sub-menu disappear if you put your mouse over the sub-menu, while the animation is still running. Having the animation is pretty, but if it gets in the way of usability, you'd rather turn it off. ;)

Comment: yeah I went ahead and took that out, its way out of my knowledge at the moment anyways to make that look good

Comment: now its just a matter of figuring out why i can do it in jsfiddle and why its not working in my dreamweaver..got the UI and the jquery in there hmm

Comment: Was making a comment asking you some stuff, but I'm glad you've worked it out! ;) Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not a padding issue, looks to me more like a javascript eventhandler issue.

The parent still has hover in javascript even though you're hovering over one of it's children. Hence, the hover won't fire for the parent when you go back to the parent.

```
$('li').hover(function(){
    // 1. Parent gets onmouseover (hover) first time. Adds .selected on it's element.
    // 2. When mouse move from parent to child, removes .selected from parent, and adds to child.
    // 3. When back from child to parent, onmouseover (hover) on parent won't fire because it already (technically one of its children) already has onmouseover.
    $('li').removeClass('selected'); 
    $(this).addClass('selected').animate(bounce);        
});
```

How to fix it in a nice way is a different question :-)

Comment: ah yes!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!thank you I can finally leave the dreaded library..much appreciated